# Expected number of picks

Tags: probability, expected-value

I was wondering how to solve the following question:

```
Q diamonds are misplaced into a jar that already had N chocolates.
If we pick items one by one at random without replacement, 
what would be the expected number of picks required to get all diamonds out.
```

Source : https://www.codechef.com/KH19MOS/problems/RANDID

I don't know how to proceed to solve it. 
I tried using the standard definition of EV, but it only got messier.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_hypergeometric_distribution

Comment: Indicator variables work here.  For each of the chocolates let $X_i$ be $1$ if the $i^{th}$ chocolate is chosen before the diamonds are all out, and $0$ otherwise.  Use Linearity and add the $Q$ diamonds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be an indicator r.v. that is equal to $1$ if the $i_{th}$ chocolate is drawn before all the  diamonds are drawn, and $0$ otherwise.

Consider $(Q+1)$ items including the $Q$ diamonds and the $i_{th}$ chocolate,
then $P(X_i) = \frac{Q}{Q+1}$

Now the expectation of an indicator variable is just the probability of the event it indicates, thus $\Bbb E[X_i] = \frac{Q}{Q+1}$

and by linearity of expectation, which operates even when the variables are not independent,

$\Bbb E[X] = \Bbb E[X_1] +\Bbb E[X_2] + ... +\Bbb E[X_N] = \frac{NQ}{Q+1}$

Finally, as this only represents the expected number of picks of *chocolates* before all diamonds are drawn, the expected number of picks to get all the *diamonds* out $= Q + \frac{NQ}{Q+1}$